# Paginador de Laravel no funciona en la vista

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Buenas amigos feliz navidad y les comento mi problema.

Estoy intentando usar el paginador de Laravel el cual me funciona en otras vistas, menos en la que les voy a colocar, sencillamente no se muestra ni hace nada, tampoco me filtra los datos, es decir, coloco Paginate(9) y me trae todos los productos, como si no hubiera paginado.

Controlador:

```
   public function getCategoryProducts($slug)
    {
       $categories = Category::where('sub_category_id', 0)->get();
       $products = Category::with('products')->where('slug', $slug)->paginate(9);

        if (empty($products)) {
            abort(403, 'Product was not found');
        }

        return view('frontend.products', [
            'categories' => $categories,
            'products' => $products
        ]);
    }
```

Modelo:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'sub_category_id'];

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);

    }
}
```

Vista:

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
      @foreach ($product->products as $product_iteration_2)
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
              <div class="card h-100">
                  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                      <div class="top-pro">
                          <a href="{{ route('product.show', $product_iteration_2->product_slug) }}"><img loading="lazy"
                                  class="card-img-top img-responsive" src="{{ asset('ui/images/fondo-nodac.png') }}"
                                  alt="{{ $product_iteration_2->name }}"
                                  style='background-image: url( "{{ \Storage::url($product_iteration_2->product_image) }}");'>
                          </a>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                      <div class="card-body">
                          <h4 class="card-title">
                              <a
                                  href="{{ route('product.show', $product_iteration_2->product_slug) }}">{{ str_limit($product_iteration_2->product_code, 38) }}</a>
                          </h4>
                          <p class="card-text">{{ str_limit($product_iteration_2->product_name, 50) }}</p>

                      </div>

                      <div class="sign_btn">

                          @guest()
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg price info-btn" data-toggle="modal1"
                                  data-target="#myModal1">
                                  <span>Sign in for Price</span>
                              </button>
                          @endguest

                          @auth()
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">
                                  $ {{ $product->product_price }}</button>

                              <a href="{{ route('user.addtocart', $product->id) }}" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Add to
                                  Cart</a>
                          @endauth
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      @endforeach
  @endforeach
  {{ $products->links() }}
  @if ($products->links())
      NO FUNCIONA ESTA MONDA
  @endif
```

Acá estoy haciendo un `return $products;` para ver que me trae la consulta, [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acá estoy comprobando que funciona el paginador, no entiendo porque en la vista no me aparece, ni filtra hasta 9 sino que los trae todos.

Aclaro que en las otras vistas si me funciona, solo que uso el paginador de la siguiente manera: `$consulta Consulta::paginate(9);` así lo uso en otros controladores y me funciona en las vistas pero en esta ocasión tengo esta consulta y al hacerle DD o sencillamente return a la consulta "Aparentemente funciona" pero en la vista no.

No se si es por el tema del doble foreach, si pudiera aclararme la duda y de ante mano gracias por cualquier sugerencia o ayuda.

Comment: Estoy teniendo el mismo problema, si se encuentras algun tipo de resolucion a este asunto sería de muchísima ayuda.
La unica resolucion encontrada hasta el momento es utilizar ->simplePagination en el controlador pero no es el resultado que quiero obtener.

Comment: Estás consultando Category y no Product, por lo que el paginador se aplica sobre las categorías y no sobre los productos. Si quieres paginar los productos, haz la consulta sobre el modelo Product